# Python data structure to store http request

Tags: python, http, header, request, response

I am looking for an ideas / tricks to process and store http request headers.
I need to preserve the order of the headers and be ready for duplicates
(even duplicates of both the key and the value).

Neither a dictionary or even the ordered dictionary will not serve the purpose here.

What data-structures are commonly used for such requirements ?

Comment: Hello and welcome! It might be worth having a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you  Abhijeetk431 for your insight but the question i asked is exactly the one i wanted to ask. And i did my homework using search engines. I am asking for experience here.

Comment: Have you tried just storing them in a list?

Comment: What does "be ready for duplicates" mean? To you need to preserve all duplicates, or ignore them? A list of tuples sounds like it would do the job in the first case, and could easily be adapted to prevent duplicates at insert time.

Comment: I need to store them exactly as i see them. Nothing can be ignored and the order must be preserved. I am talking here about even the most non-RFC compliant requests.

Comment: @RoadRunner: do you mean both keys and values in a single list (even index for key and odd for a value) or two separate lists, one for keys and one for values ? I am more asking for experience and ease of use/lookup. It would also be nice to call the value by name and not number (like in a dict)

Comment: @PeteNoc: given that you need to store them verbatim I think that a list of `(header, value)` tuples is what you need. It will preserve order and duplicates.

Comment: Ok let us make it insane, but i need to be ready for this and not to loose anything (order or content): Host: abc.com, User-Agent: Mozilla, Host:123.com, TE: chunked, User-Agent: Safari.  I am asking for experience in regards to ease of both storage and later lookup, preferably lookup by name.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the brainstorm. This led me to named tuples. Will dig deeper into it. Thx for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list of `(header, value)` tuples (or `collections.namedtuple`):

```
headers = [('Host', 'abc.com'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla'), ('Host', '123.com'), ('TE', 'chunked'), ('User-Agent', 'Safari')]
```

This will preserve the order of entry of each header, and will also preserve duplicates.

Lookup will not be as efficient as a dictionary, but (presumably) the number of headers per request is not going to be very large. You can lookup using a list comprehension, or a generator expression if that's more suitable. Example 
lookup for `User-Agent`:

```
user_agents = [header for header in headers if header[0].lower() == 'user-agent']
>>> user_agents
[('User-Agent', 'Mozilla'), ('User-Agent', 'Safari')]
```

It's fairly easy to wrap that up in a class that provides `add_header(header, value)` and`get_header(header)` methods. You could provide dict like lookup by name by implementing `__getitem__()`. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: @PeteNoc: no problem. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer :)

Comment: My upvote was ignored (I am a rookie here ;-) ), looking for the "Accept" button now.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries can work for this:
Suppose you have a list of tuples(header,value)
eg:

```
headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla'),('User-Agent', 'Chrome'), ('Content-Type', 'application/json')]

values= {}

for k, v in headers:
    setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

This will preserve the entry order and also duplicates

```
print(values)
{'User-Agent': ['Mozilla', 'Chrome'], 'Content-Type': ['application/json']}
```